# css linear gradient not working in any browser

Tags: css

```
<!doctye html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body{
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
            background:linear-gradient(top,#f7fob7 0% ,#b57c12 100%);
            background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f7fob7 0% ,#b57c12 100%);
            background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#f7fob7 0%,#b57c12 100%); 
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-top:10px;

        }
        </style>
        <title>
        Title
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>

    CSS gradients are new types of <image> added in the CSS3 Image Module.
    </p>

    </body>

</html>
```

but gradient does not change any thing ,background color works but gradient no work me tested in Chorme and firefox can u help what wrong .

Comment: `#f7fob7` this is not valid color value , should be `#f7f0b7`, **'o'**-> **'0'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have error in hex color code. Change `#f7fob7` (with letter `o`) to `#f7f0b7` (with zero).

```css
.a {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f0b7 0, #b57c12 100%);/* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, color-stop(0, f7f0b7), color-stop(100%, b57c12));/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f0b7 0, #b57c12 100%);/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f0b7 0, #b57c12 100%);/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f0b7 0, #b57c12 100%);/* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #f7f0b7 0, #b57c12 100%);/* W3C */
  }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Some text here
  </div>
```